# Getting Excel to display data at specific times

Tags: excel, sorting, filter

I have an Excel spreadsheet with columns of data like this:

[image]

I want to apply a filter so that only data at 10:00 and 22:00 are displayed, but when I try to apply a custom filter it comes up blank.  My custom filter is 'Show rows where' DateTime equal ????-??-??  10:00  And  ????-??-??  22:00

But it comes up empty.  What am I missing?

Comment: Thinking about it, can the `DateTime` be equal to 10:00 AND 22:00 at the same moment in time? - if anything, it would be one OR the other (right?)

Comment: @blurfus yes you are correct and incorrect at the same time. If he would have said one OR the other then it would mean either one is fine. But he wants both values from the table so AND is the correct way of saying it.

Comment: @Andreas I still do not understand but I am glad someone did ;)

Comment: As I understand it, he wants to keep 2017-08-03 10:00, 2017-08-03 22:00, 2017-08-04 10:00 from the image and the rest should be hidden

Comment: I want it to display both 10:00 and 22:00 for all dates.

Comment: Yes, so look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Edited the formula, I noticed my error.

You can add a helper column with the following formula.

```
=IF(OR((A2-TRUNC(A2))=(1/24*22),(A2-TRUNC(A2))=(1/24*10)),"Yes","No")
```

And fill down.
Now you have a column that you can easily filter on since it looks at the "time"- part of the datetime cell.

1/10 and 1/22 results in the fraction that is part of the datetime of your cell.

This answer assumes the datetime is in column A and that the cells is proper datetime cells and not strings.

The value in a datetime cell is a float value of say 1.5 that translates to 1900-01-02 12:00:00.
Because it's 1.5 days after 1900-01-01.
So by using the formula 1/24 you get what one hour is in float value.
1/24*22 is the float value of the time 22:00.

So if we remove the integer part of the date time and compare against the float value times then we know what cells is 10:00 or 22:00

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper column for the Hours with formula:

```
=Hour(A2)
```

Then filter on  that column.

You can either just select the `10` and `22` from the dropdown, or use a custom number filter with value = 10 OR value = 22

[image]

[image]